# Laplace Question with Unit step starting at 10

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the Laplace transform of f(t)=10e^(-200t)u(t-10). Would it be correct to take out the 10 because it is a constant, find the Laplace transform of e^(-200t) and then multiply it by the Laplace transform of u(t-10) to obtain a final answer of : 10(1/(s+200))(e^(-10s))? The u(t-10) is what is really confusing me in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite: the Laplace transform of the product is not the product of the Laplace transforms. However, there is a formula for this situation, which you can derive like this:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-st} u(t-c) f(t) dt = \int_0^c e^{-st} u(t-c) f(t) dt + \int_c^\infty e^{-st} u(t-c) f(t) dt \\
= 0 + \int_c^\infty e^{-st} f(t) dt \\
= \int_0^\infty e^{-s(t+c)} f(t+c) dt \\
= e^{-cs} \int_0^\infty e^{-st} f(t+c) dt$$

In other words:

$$\mathcal{L}(f(t) u(t-c))=e^{-cs} \mathcal{L}(f(t+c)).$$

Comment: So, the correct answer should therefore be 10*e^(-10s)*(1/(s+200))*e^(-200(10))?

Comment: @user131763 That appears to be correct (just checking with Wolfram Alpha).